# nloptr not returning lowest solution so far after reaching maxeval

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nlopt

I am looking to find a good (not necessarily the best) solution to a non linear function with non linear constraints. I have searched around for the most appropriate method and I think that nlopt is the best option with the GN_ISRES algorithm.

the function is minimising distance between two sets of points with the following constraints

- all points must be integers
- points must have coordinates that are either both even or both odd
- no point can be the same as another

Below is my reproducible example code, my main issue is that even when starting with a bad solution, when maxeval is reached the solution stored is still the starting one, rather than the best solution from the iterations do far.

Why is this the case and is there a way to make it return the best solution so far?

```
library(nloptr)

coords = data.frame(
  name = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  lat = c(45,46,48,42,36),
  lon = c(1,3,2,5,4)
)

hexbin_coords = data.frame(
  name = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  y = c(41,42,43,44,45)
)

eval_f <- function(z, lat, lon) {
  y = z[((length(z)/2)+1):length(z)]
  x = z[1:(length(z)/2)]
  distance = sum(sqrt((x - lat)^2 + (y - lon)^2))
  return(distance)
}

## constraints
eval_g <- function(z, lat, lon) {
  y = z[((length(z)/2)+1):length(z)]
  x = z[1:(length(z)/2)]
  sum1 = sum((x - y) %% 2)
  sum2 = sum(z %% 1)
  #sum2 = 0
  sum3 = any(duplicated(apply(data.frame(x,rep("a",length(x)),y), 1, paste, collapse="")))
  return(sum1 + sum2 + sum3)
}

opts <- list( "algorithm"= "NLOPT_GN_ISRES",
              "xtol_rel"= 1.0e-7,
              "maxeval"= 10,
              "print_level" = 3)

sol <- nloptr(x0 = c(hexbin_coords$x, hexbin_coords$y),
              eval_f = eval_f,
              eval_g_eq = eval_g,
              lb = rep(0,10),
              ub = rep(50,10),
              opts = opts,
              lat = coords$lat,
              lon = coords$lon
)
print(sol)
```

Comment: I think this question would fit better on MathOverflow or another more math-focused community. It doesn't relate to software enough to be on StackOverflow.

Comment: If an alternative method would be acceptable, too, you could also try with an optimization heuristic, such as Differential Evolution. (A quick and dirty run with `NMOF::DEopt`gave me a solution `c(45, 45, 48, 41, 36, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4)`.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `nloptr` does not provide this functionality directly, so the only option is to scrape the output you get via `print_level=3` for the values:

```
library(stringr) # For string matching and extracting

sol.output <- capture.output(sol <- nloptr(x0 = c(hexbin_coords$x, hexbin_coords$y),
                        eval_f = eval_f,
                        eval_g_eq = eval_g,
                        lb = rep(0,10),
                        ub = rep(50,10),
                        opts = opts,
                        lat = coords$lat,
                        lon = coords$lon)) # capture the "print" output to a variable

sol.hist <- sol.output[grepl("\tx",sol.output)] #get all lines starting with a tab and x (Those are the lines with the variables)
sol.hist <- sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(sol.hist,"[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"),as.numeric) # Extract all numbers and convert to numeric
rownames(sol.hist) <- paste0("Iteration_",seq_len(nrow(sol.hist))) #set some descriptive names
colnames(sol.hist) <- paste0("Variable_",seq_len(ncol(sol.hist)))
sol.hist

            Iteration_1 Iteration_2 Iteration_3 Iteration_4 Iteration_5 Iteration_6 Iteration_7 Iteration_8
Variable_1            1   41.870830   12.911006    2.279217    2.857534   24.370609   21.847667   11.074417
Variable_2            2   28.649218   20.234235    9.663595   37.479727    7.707112   17.469032   48.587274
Variable_3            3   28.547109   48.541501   29.354267   24.670474   16.181966    4.559475   21.171942
Variable_4            4    4.529856    0.221904   15.666075   13.072797   24.905793   39.300537   29.968914
Variable_5            5   13.938569   25.595069   43.422727   15.680567   27.393603    8.527784   47.716471
Variable_6           41   17.493988   31.714159   16.504085   48.342804   34.445824   32.355841    2.347884
Variable_7           42   20.647009   42.209615   23.079238   22.102841    7.842979   27.584622    7.954957
Variable_8           43   33.884236   24.857512    4.001447   39.029162   39.050927   38.151746   19.158068
Variable_9           44   39.405297    4.173269   48.558713   48.976114   48.358011   30.155023    6.904914
Variable_10          45   20.769793   29.435024    0.124530   21.440616   24.843518   28.395304    6.854763
```

With this approach you do not only get the "best" value but a complete history of all values. So you can also plot optimization graphs etc.